# GridPane Xgap only on specific borders

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to apply the `Vgap` and `Hgap` properties of a `GridPane` only to specific borders?

Plus: Is it possible to omit the outside borders?

Comment: Maybe inset the content of the desired node?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Gaps are not on the borders; it's _between_ nodes.

Comment: So maybe a GridPane has a mandatory margin around it?

Comment: You need to show what you mean because the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nope, margins are something else. Maybe you're refering to padding (once again, something else)?

Answer (score -1):

If you are capable of switching off GridPane I'd suggest maybe trying out MigPane/MigLayout, much more easily configured gaps/spacing around everything.

```
compile group: 'com.miglayout', name: 'miglayout-core', version: '5.0'
compile group: 'com.miglayout', name: 'miglayout-javafx', version: '5.0'
```

Are the dependencies you'll need if you can/do go this route.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Can it integrate with Scene Builder?

Comment: If i may suggest, GridPane is the most powerful layout parent of all. First understand what the op's problem is, because it's very unclear.

Comment: Mig doesn't 'work' so easily with scene builder as its code isn't easy for the scene builder to modify the simple string-based constraints of how the panels are defined, but it can be viewed in SceneBuilder if I recall correctly.

@MouseEvent Perhaps, but in my experience its also the least easy for people who don't understand its intricacies or aren't using an extended form of it such as that provided by JFXtras to grasp and use, as far as I see it MigPane is merely an easier form of GridPane to use.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I got the thing wrong - the borders are as I expected them I was just looking at the wrong numbers - sorry to bother you and thank you to all who tried to help me with this messy question :-)